# What classes of aircraft require hydraulic flight controls?

Tags: flight-controls

All commercial airliners such as the Boeing 737 or Airbus A320 or heavier aircraft require an hydraulic system that can power actuators, which generate the required forces to move the control surfaces in all phases of flight. Smaller General Aviation aircraft do not need this.

But what about aircraft in between? Is there a minimum MTOW above which aircraft are required to or generally have an hydraulic system? Can you make examples of lighter aircraft which have it?

For example I was wondering about the an aircraft like the 19-passenger commuter [Beechcraft 1900](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beechcraft_1900):
[image: Beechcraft 1900]

Comment: Required by whom? Are you asking if it's an actual regulatory requirement or something else?

Comment: @DavidRicherby Edited for clarity

Comment: The Beech 1900 uses cable controls, not hydraulics, for flight controls. The exception would be the rudder boost which is used in emergencies. I also know that the DC-9 series, including the MD-88/90, uses cable controls, but I don't know if they are boosted. I also don't know what regulation, if any, regulates this matter.

Comment: Hm. Are the only control systems used control cables attached directly to stick or hydraulics? Are there inbetween fly by wire systems that use electric winches on the control cables or some kind of electric actuator on the control surface directly?

Comment: @StarWeaver There are many possibilities. The 737 for example features mechanically linked flight controls, which are assisted by hydraulic power. The principle of fly-by-wire systems is to decouple the stick/horn from the control surface, so what you suggest is contradictory. Electric actuators are also used, as opposed to hydraulic ones. Fly-by-wire transmits the control input, hydraulics or electric actuators provide the power to move the surfaces.

Comment: @mezzanaccio Ah, cool. I didn't mean to suggest systems that were only partially fly-by-wire; I was just curious if there were any other FBW systems between the presented dichotomy of fly-by-cable and FBW/hydraulic. (Also now I'm curious about the etymolgy of 'horn', as in my mostly-spaceflight mostly-non-realistic sim and reading-about-airplanes history i've only ever heard 'stick' variants.)

Comment: @StarWeaver sorry what I meant was yoke... I lived too long in Germany.

Comment: @mezzanaccio Ah yeah I do know that one. Tho now i'm imagining some fancy texan's cessna with a custom yoke that is largely made out of bull hornsW

Comment: I don't see how your edit addresses my question at all. Again, are you asking about regulatory requirements or matters of engineering?

Comment: @DavidRicherby And I do not see how you cannot understand the question. It is simple: big A/C have hydraulics. Small ones do not. Which A/C in between do (example)? Are there explicit regulatory requirements? Yes or no.

Comment: The repeated use of the word "require"-- as well as the suggestion that you are looking for a specific numerical value for a MTOW threshold-- and the use of the word "class" which is word that has regulatory significance-- suggests that this *may* be a question about regulations. (And several of the answers seemed to have assumed that it was.) It would be clearer if you simply added a sentence saying "This is not a question about *regulatory requirements*, just about what has been found to be necessary during the actual design and flight testing of aircraft." Or something to that effect. –

Comment: Wait a minute now I see your last comment says you are asking *both* about regulatory requirements and practical requirements.  I know it's an old question but it would sure be clearer if had asked in two parts a) are there regulatory requirements and b) if not, in actual practice where is the threshold where hydraulic control systems have been found to be necessary -- or something like that--

Comment: @StarWeaver - “a custom yoke that is largely made out of bull horns” - That actually does not sound like a bad idea. Maybe from a Brangus with matching Longhorns on the cowl. How much drag penalty would that incur?  Just yoking.

Answer (score 8):

Hydraulic flight controls are not mandatory for a specific class, but above some size and speed it will be hard to fulfil [all certification requirements](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=eff98f0002228524f60ed5fbc5c8c1e6&mc=true&node=se14.1.25_1143&rgn=div8) without at least adding some hydraulic boost.

Historically, aircraft used manual controls. With increasing size and speed, the forces went up and [increasingly clever](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/15673/what-is-the-working-principle-of-trim-tabs-on-the-elevators/15674#15674) force [reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servo_tab) systems [were invented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_control_surfaces#Control_horn) to [keep stick forces](http://naca.central.cranfield.ac.uk/reports/1938/naca-tn-653.pdf) within [limits](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1000/what-makes-the-ailerons-on-an-aerobatic-airplane-different-than-the-ailerons-on/1085#1085).

- On the first flight of the [Messerschmitt Me-321](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Messerschmitt_Me_321) glider it was found that control forces especially in roll were way too high, so a second pilot with a second stick was installed.
- The [Dornier Do-335](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dornier_Do_335) or the [Republic P-47](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republic_P-47_Thunderbolt) used a telescopic stick: At low speed the stick was short and could move through the full range of aileron deflections while at high speed it could be telescopically extended. This limited the motion range but improved the leverage of the pilot.
- The [English Electric Canberra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_Electric_Canberra) used internal balances for the ailerons and a spring in the aileron controls to limit the stick forces. At top speed the control horn could still move through its full range but the achievable aileron deflections were only a few degrees - still enough for sufficient roll agility, however.

Ailerons have mass. There is a spring. Something that moves. Every engineer should think next: What about flutter? With more complex force reductions, the chance grew that something unexpected happens and failure modes multiplied. In the end, introducing hydraulics solved so many problems that de facto above a certain speed and size combination no other option makes sense.

I have worked together with Rockwell (formerly North American) on a two seat jet trainer; a size and speed combination that would have had manual controls 60 years ago. I proposed to use the same force reduction mechanisms that were used on the F-86, but in the end a hydraulic boost was selected. Why?

- Nobody had any experience with manual controls anymore. After so many years, all F-86-era engineers were long retired or had passed away.
- The North American archives had been thrown away years before, so no documentation was left on how to properly design a manual control system for that speed range.
- The hydraulic boost system was easy to install, used standard components and was cheaper to design because everybody was familiar with the technology.

As I [said before](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/17019/why-does-the-yoke-stick-in-a-turning-position/17025#17025): Don't get me started on how exactly you can tailor roll stick forces - this will be a post that will be much longer than anything I have written here before.

Comment: Peter! I look forward to reading your memoirs! will you write a book? -NN

Comment: @nielsnielsen To be fair, I think the memoirs of the guy who made inkjet printing viable will be a much more interesting read. And if you take together my many answers, there is not much left to tell.

Comment: @OMG Peter how did you find that out????????????

Comment: @nielsnielsen I have my ways … :-)

Comment: @nielsnielsen It was back then when your profile picture showed you with a guitar. I was intrigued and checked out your web pages where I found a link to a document which described what you did at HP.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there is no hard regulation requiring hydraulics at a certain point. On one hand the aircraft need to actually be controllable so if that would be unattainable at operational speeds then hydraulics would bee needed.

[In the FAA's Brief on flight controls](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/phak/media/08_phak_ch6.pdf)

> As aviation matured and aircraft designers learned more about
>   aerodynamics, the industry produced larger and faster aircraft.
>   Therefore, the aerodynamic forces acting upon the control surfaces
>   increased exponentially. To make the control force required by pilots
>   manageable, aircraft engineers designed more complex systems. At
>   first, hydromechanical designs, consisting of a mechanical circuit and
>   a hydraulic circuit, were used to reduce the complexity, weight, and
>   limitations of mechanical flight controls systems.

The [FAR's list the limits of force on a control input in FAA FAR 23.397](https://www.gpo.gov/fdsys/pkg/CFR-2011-title14-vol1/pdf/CFR-2011-title14-vol1-sec23-399.pdf)

> (a) In the control surface flight loading condition, **the airloads on
>   movable surfaces and the corresponding deflections need not exceed
>   those that would result in flight from the application of any pilot
>   force within the ranges specified in paragraph (b) of this section.** In
>   applying this criterion, **the effects of control system boost and
>   servo-mechanisms, and the effects of tabs must be considered.** The
>   automatic pilot effort must be used for design if it alone can produce
>   higher control surface loads than the human pilot.

Keep in mind this does not require hydraulics outright but if you can not build a cable/trim tab system that falls within these force limits you will need to add in some kind of assistance.

Comment: "uneatable"? Autoincorrect malfunction?

Comment: I get hungry when I fly sometimes, with to much control surface force I cant eat.... See correction ;)

Comment: @JonathanWalters My question was also about part 23 aircraft. The Beechcraft 1900 is a part 23 aircraft. I guess if it does not have hydraulics then no part 23 aircraft does.

Comment: @mezzanaccio Thats part of my point, but my comment wasn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a particular weight or size class for requiring hydraulic flight controls. The requirements are for control forces to stay within certain bounds, and in general this becomes more difficult with increasing size and speed of the aircraft.

Keeping the control system manual has the advantage that the aeroforces are fed back to the pilot, and that with increasing airspeed the controls stiffen up, making it harder to making large deflections which would impose high accelerations on the airframe. But larger/faster aircraft require larger control surfaces, with the associated larger control forces. However the control forces must remain within the boundaries of human force ability.

[image]

Many of the older hydraulically actuated aircraft have some form of feedback of aircraft velocity. The 737 has q-feel in the pitch channel: an artificial feel system stiffens up the flight control as a function of dynamic pressure as sensed by the pitot tube. The DC-10 and the L-1011 have this as well.

In a previous life I used to contract for simulator modelling of flight control systems of fixed wing and helicopter flight controls, and the Beech 1900 is one of the types that I worked on. It has a fully manual control system, all aeroforces are fed back to the pilot. The pitch channel has a down spring of about 40 lbf, which is apparent from ground measurements. Have heard comments about the pitch forces being high during landing, and that particularly female pilots can have trouble exerting these forces during landings. Hydraulic actuation may make it easier to fly the aircraft and tailor the required forces. There are larger and faster aircraft certified for manual control, the F100 is one: pitch has manual backup.