# What was the first airplane fitted with a hydraulic system?

Tags: aviation-history, hydraulic-system

What was the first airplane fitted with hydraulic system?

Where was it used?

What are the fundamental differences between the first systems and those that are used now?

Comment: related, perhaps dupe: http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/35224/what-aircraft-had-the-first-pilot-assisted-controls

Comment: Hydraulic brake systems are a type of hydraulic system. Do you want to include or exclude those from your question?

Comment: Include of course

Comment: @wiaim I ask because hydraulic brakes are commonly separate systems from the "hydraulic systems" that are often discussed. The meaning is not obvious; I would have presumed that you meant to exclude braking systems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What was the first airplane fitted with hydraulic system?/Where was it used?

If we exclude hydraulic disk brake systems.

[The Lockheed Constellation most likely had the first hydraulic flight controls (introduced in '43)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_Constellation)

[Introduced in '27 the Fairchild FC-1/FC-2 had hydraulically operated landing gear and disk brakes.](http://www.all-aero.com/index.php/contactus/45-planes-d-e-f/3406-fairchild-fc-1-fc-2)

> What are the fundamental differences between the first systems and
>   those that are used now?

Depending on how you look at it, little. Hydraulics are hydraulics. The systems have gotten more powerful but that may be related to the available power to drive the pumps. We arguably have gotten better at building them and they are perhaps more reliable but they are still more or less the same in operation.

Comment: The DC3 introduced in 1936 had multiple hydraulic systems including for brakes, gear retraction, flaps, and cowl flaps. I know the earlier DC2 also had hydraulics, at least for gear retraction.

Comment: The Fairchild FC-1/FC-2 had fixed, conventional gear. In what way were these hydraulically operated landing gear?

Comment: @JonathanWalters Im still trying to figure it out but multiple sources state that it had hydraulically operated landing gear.

Comment: It may have had "hydraulic" shock absorbers but it couldn't have hydraulically operated gear. They are hydraulic in the same sense the shocks/struts in your car are hydraulic...